# Can a bug in a perl program using Perl/TK cause memory corruption

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have the unfortunate task of maintaining an orphaned Perl program that uses Perl/TK to create a GUI and crashes in some situations with errors like

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/perl: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000003daf500 ***
```

Is it basically possible for a Perl program to contain a bug that causes such behaviour or can I safely assume that a bug in the Perl interpreter and/or Perl/Tk is responsible and waiting for a new version of those tools might be the best approach to get rid of this problem?

EDIT: To make my question more clear: would a bug like attempting to destroy a widget twice or calling a method on an already destroyed widget result in a clean error message or could it cause the problems I'm experiencing?

EDIT2: The Perl version is  `5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi`

And it uses this modules:

```
use Tie::Watch;
use Tk;
use Tk::Balloon;
use Tk::Compound;
use Tk::DialogBox;
use Tk::LabFrame;
use Tk::NoteBook;
use Tk::Pane;
use Tk::ROText;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple::DTDReader;
```

Comment: Could you please add information on the version of perl and the modules you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but in this case unlikely.

There are multiple ways to directly access (and modify) program memory in Perl (and for that matter, any programming language). There are extensions for this (Win32::Process::Memory for Windows), but under Linux the easiest way would be to open /proc/*pid*/map (process memory, mapped to a random-access file) and manipulate that.

So, definitely possible.

It is however **very unlikely** that your Perl program is using any of these tricks to manipulate its own memory directly. As you thought, the most likely culprit is one of the libraries used (Tk in this case).

You could try to use [Devel::Trace](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel%3a%3aTrace) module to see what the program is trying to do just before its crashes.

If you can find that it is always crashing on a particular line, you could try to alter its behavior to avoid triggering the bug in underlying libraries. That's a bit of hit-and-miss affair, though.

If someone has knowledge of this kind of bug in Perl/Tk that could be helpful. Is your program using other libraries using C libraries (e.g. not "pure perl" libraries) than Tk?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that the program doesn't access /proc/pid/map directly or does anything like that. From what I see in the source, it also uses DBI, Data::Dumper and XML::Simple::DTDReader; I guess some of them are not pure perl.

Comment: I ran it with Devel::Trace, and the crash happens in /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Tk/Widget.pm:360  Some changes in my program (disabling the bit of code that did the call) just made it crash at another place, but still in Widget.pm

Comment: I've seen this sort of problem if (1) an extension is compiled with a different version of compiler/different settings from the rest of the system. Or, (2) threaded code accessing non-thread-safe code. Not sure if either is relevant to you, but worth bearing in mind if your testing on Tk doesn't find the problem.

Comment: Simple `pack`/`unpack` with `p` or `P` template will do fine too.

Comment: The core of Tk is pretty thoroughly tested; it's unlikely to have many problems like this. _However_ I've no idea about the extra modules on top or the Perl binding.

Comment: As Richard noted, a possible culprit is library version mismatch. You **could** try to build a copy of Perl and all the required libraries from scratch and test the application on the locally compiled version.

This isn't as daunting as it first sounds. Perl's build system is quite robust. You'll need to give it a prefix that doesn't conflict with system paths (--prefix $HOME/my-local-perl), then make sure that install's bin path is first in PATH, and then just start using the my-local-perl version cpan installer to install the libraries you need.